# In dart polymer how to define nested custom element?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to build a library for custom elements with Dart Polymer, the architecture looks like this:

```
<parent-custom-element attributes="xxxx">
<child-custom-element-0 attributes="yyyyy">     </child-custom-element-0>
<child-custom-element-1 attributes="zzzzzzzz">     </child-custom-element-1>
</parent-custom-element>
```

The requirement is that: the child-custom-element could access the DOM/variables/object of the parent-custom-element. For example, if the parent-custom-element has a canvas object, the child-custom-element could draw line, or circle on it.

Any ideas how to do it? Or any examples to guide me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about nesting polymer elements:

http://www.roberthartung.de/nested-polymer-elements-and-data-binding-in-googles-dart/

This should help you to understand how to nest elements. Feel free to ask further questions!

Regards
Robert

Comment: Thanks for option. However, I have to know how to have data-binding between parent and child elements here.

Comment: Isn't that what I am showing? You can't to it as you posted, because the child elements won't show up anyway. You have to move them to the parent's shadowDom. I think you will have to create the data binding manually.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I have to move them into the parent's shadowDOM. After that, I was trying to create the data binding manually, but never succeeded. Is there any reason? Thanks!

Comment: How dou you try to initialize the databinding? You just need to make your inner child' attribute observable and use the databinding normally in the child element. In the parent element you can then use `child.myAttr = this.myAttr;` (this is used here to better show what I mean). Then a databinding should be working.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the code below:                                                     ChildElement child = shadowRoot.querySelector('child-element');
    dataObject = new DataObject();
    child.dataObject = dataObject; .            The problem is that, when dataObject is chaning [by clicking the button in child element], the parent-element DOM will update, but child-element will not. Therefore, I think we have data binding between the two elements, but how to make the child-elment DOM update with the data?

Comment: I put together a very detailed description what I tried in the google group, please take a look!

Comment: Ok. I commented there. :)

For everyone that is interested in the google group's thread:

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/rIwW-bYm4zw